# Mandrill - View In Browser Functionality

Tags: mandrill

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14854072/mandrill-and-view-in-browser-functionality) was discussed about 2 years ago.

Do we have any feature built-in Mandrill since then to cater to the requirement mentioned in that link of displaying every email sent through Mandrill in browser by adding a "View In Browser" link? If not, then I am leaning towards implementing something similar to what @Muleskinner did (again mentioned in that link as one of the responses). Please let me know what you guys think about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have managed to implement the requirement mentioned above. Explanation below for anyone else looking for help on the same subject:

Mandrill still DOES NOT have any such feature out of the box. So we need to implement this on our own. What I am doing is immediately after sending every email through Mandrill, I call its Render method which gives the resultant parsed template in HTML with all customers' information and storing it in the system for future use.

Answer (score 0):

Would strongly recommend using a full-featured templating service on top of mandrill (we use [sendwithus](http://sendwithus.com). Services like that provide a templated URL that can power this sort of thing, and you won't have to worry about building and hosting the templates yourself.